# Data Explorer: Figure out deleted answers / total answers ratio

Tags: support, data-explorer

I'm list the users with the highest deleted answers / total answers ratio. I'm not even sure if it is possible though... is it? If so, would someone care to show me how to get started on such a query?

Comment: It's impossible.  Deleted questions are not in the Data Dump.

Comment: That's a shame :-( Write it as an answer (and give a reference if you have) and I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Data Dump only contains public data.

Deleted answers are not public data -- they are only visible to the post owner and 10k rep users (and higher). Further, the Data Dump does not contain deleted content of any kind, and other types of data are anonymized as well (such as who voted on which posts, and when).

If you're only curious about your own deleted answer ratio, unfortunately it would be nearly impossible to figure out as well, as there are no search features that operate on deleted posts (neither your own, nor others' posts). Diamond moderators and devs may be able to see users' deleted answers (they can see their deleted questions), but that certainly isn't a scalable way of figuring this out.

Comment: That is a shame, that data could have been made available to authenticated users with the correct reputation.