# Epic badge received too early?

Tags: support, badges, daily-reputation-badges, reputation-page

There are already many questions about the epic badge and that it was assigned too late, but:

I have just received the [Epic badge](https://tex.stackexchange.com/badges/42/epic) on http://tex.stackexchange.com after earning 200 rep today (which incl. 2x15 for two accepted answers).
However the rep listing under https://tex.stackexchange.com/reputation states for me:

```
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 41 days
rep cap was exceeded on 48 days
```

I had been keeping an eye on those numbers so the badge came as a surprise. Is this an error? I'd really like to earn the badge ;-).

Also just to clarify: Must the rep cap be hit, i.e. must a limitation have been encountered? By this I mean you got 21 up-votes at one day (20 to get the max 200 rep + 1 to hit the limitation, which is than listed as `[0]` in the listing). Or is it enough to get 200 (or 200+) rep points in any combination? My listing tells me that both of these values are below 50 times. I've tried hitting the recalculate button, with no change.

---

Ok, I manually recounted all days where I got 200 or more rep. I actually count 50 of them, however on one I had exactly 200 which might not count for the `rep cap was exceeded on` number while counting for the badge. This makes 49 days. I thought the last missing one might simply be because the day isn't over, but now it is 5 min after midnight UTC and it is still just 48.

---

The same -2 offset happened now to me with the Legendary badge:

```
rep cap was reached via rep from upvotes *only* on 111 days
earned at least 200 reputation on 148 days
```

I don't mind it at this point, but in general there should be an exact display of the days available.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisF. That's about the same question, just for the *Legendary* badge. The `SUM(targetrepchange) >= 200` in Jeff's answer seems to indicate that *only* 200 or more rep is required without actually encountering a limitation. However, stating that for non SQL-masters would enrich that answer.

Comment: Both of the linked/duplicate questions in the comments have disappeared. This just happened to me with Legendary...

Comment: Just happened the same to me with 46 days.

Answer (score 22):

The `/reputation` audit trail shows you totals per day *minus deleted posts*.

The count towards the Epic and Legendary badges counts days that you reached 200 points *without* removing deleted posts, I believe.

So if you reached 200+ points on a given day but later a question you answered is removed and losing the rep gained from your answer puts you below 200 again, the day still counts towards the badges but the `/reputation` list does not include it in the count at the bottom.

In your case it looks like there were 2 such days; you still earned the badge but the audit trail won't reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

If @Martijn Pieters' answer is correct ([which seems so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/61173/172011)) then all *Epic/Legendary badge* calculation queries on the [SE Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) are useless! The data dump [does not contain deleted data](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71385/172011).

<sub>Many of the queries are useless in the first place since [days where you get 200+ rep count towards the badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88526/172011) and not as [many](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33189/im-confused-about-the-epic-badge), many [people](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114251/epic-and-legendary-hit-the-cap-or-just-reach-200) are [confused](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/32104/legendary-badge-calculation) about and queries imply - the rep cap.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I received the Epic badge recently and my `/reputation` page showed I reached 200 rep only 46 times.

What was interesting is: even though the badges page records all the Epic badges as received at midnight, I received mine in the middle of the day, a few minutes after I reached 200 points on that day.

That made me think that the way the badge is calculated is that you have to **reach** 200 points on a given day for it to be counted. It doesn't matter if some of those points are later taken away (I can think of 4 ways: downvoting answers, deletions, unacceptance of an accepted answer and placing a bounty).

Comment: In other words, [exactly what Martijn said](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/165634/223030).

Comment: @michaelb958 Yes, though I extended it to all kinds of negative reputation you can get.